# Can a VM be part of multiple environments defined in different projects?

Tags: azure-devops

I was wondering if it is possible to have a VM configured as part of an environment in different Azure DevOps projects and if these can exist in completely different Azure DevOps organizations or if running the PowerShell script that adds a VM to an environment detached the VM from any previous environment it was part of.

Comment: Hi whatever. You've posted your question in the wrong forum. Please refer to this: https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @FlorianKamps This is a perfectly on-topic question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same VM for hosting agents for different AzDo projects and even different tenants.
If you are installing VM agents through the `Environments` section, and your VM is running two different environments, you would need two agents.

Answer (score 1):

You can install multiple copies of the agent, each connected to different Azure DevOps organization. One agent can't be connected to multiple organizations.